# Sepia tone via wand api (using wand-py) produces completely wrong image (no sepia, high brightness)

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

Using wand-py I've registered MagickSepiaToneImage
http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickSepiaToneImage
and then applied on a image

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library

library.MagickSepiaToneImage.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_double]
library.MagickSepiaToneImage.restype = None

img = Image(filename="img.jpg")
library.MagickSepiaToneImage(img.wand, 80.0)
img.save(filename="out.jpg")
```

It really bright image, almost white with few contoures preserved. It looks  similar to brightness changed to maximum. The result is completely different from console command
`convert img.jpg -sepia-tone 80% out.jpg`

Changing threshold argument has no effect. It seems to be just ignored.
Is there some basic mistake? Because I am using few other method in similar way (eg. MagickModulateImage) with no issue.

(my libmagickwand-dev library version is 8:6.7.7.10+dfsg-4ubuntu1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that threshold of 80% is a number between 0 and QuantumRange.

```py
import ctypes
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library

library.MagickSepiaToneImage.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_double]
library.MagickSepiaToneImage.restype = None

img = Image(filename="img.jpg")
threshold = img.quantum_range * 0.8
library.MagickSepiaToneImage(img.wand, threshold)
img.save(filename="out.jpg")
```